# WheelView change setCurrentItem doesn´t work

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a problem with WheelView using [these library](https://github.com/chemalarrea/Android-wheel).  I've created a Dialog in which I want to put a WheelView, but i can't change current item and I can't figure about what the problem is, code:

```
public class SpeedDialog extends AlertDialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
    private Activity activity;
    TextView textView;
    int current = 50;

    public SpeedDialog(Activity activity, int theme) {
        super(activity, theme);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.speed_dialog);
        WheelView wheelView = (WheelView)findViewById(R.id.wheel_speed);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_value);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        wheelView.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(activity, 50, 200, "%1.2f", 100));
        wheelView.addChangingListener(new OnWheelChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
                setCurrent(newValue);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
            }
        });
        wheelView.setCurrentItem(getcurrent());
    }

    public Integer getcurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(int current) {
        this.current = current;
    }
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getid()) {
            case R.id.apply:
                dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The libraries you provide has not been update for more than 4 years, that maybe the reason<br/>

try one the following alternative <br/>
https://github.com/maarek/android-wheel <br/>
https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel

Answer (score 0):

Solved using sharedpreferences to save and load value